# How to generate MD5 Hash(32/64 Characters) from an integer

Tags: c#, .net, hash, integer, md5

I have Googled and checked

> How to generate MD5 Hash(32/64 Characters) from an integer?

What I got is there are examples for generating an MD5 hash string from a string or from a byte array. But in my case, I need to get the  MD5 hash of an integer.

I know that the `GetHashCode()` method is there to get the hash code for an integer. But this method is not applicable in my case.

Do I need to convert the integer to a string or byte array to get the expected MD5 hash string?

Comment: It depends a lot on what kind of output you expect. You can either hash the string representation, or the bytes of the integer; both will be valid but yield different results.

Comment: Unless your integer is a "special" long integer (like `BigInteger`) it is a 32 bit or 64 bit value. A MD5 hash is a 128 bit value so why do you want to hash an integer? You can just use the integer as the hash value and you even now that each "hash" is unique. E.g., two different integers will not have the same "hash" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you All.After referring all the answers, here i am posting my answer which is containg Generic methods for Generating "MD5 Hash(32/64 Characters) from an integer/string/byte array". Might be helpful for others.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConvertIntToHashCodeConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 100;
            Console.WriteLine(GetHashMD5(number.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(GetHashStringFromInteger(number));
            Console.Read();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Hash Value for MD5 Hash(32 Characters) from an integer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="number"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHashStringFromInteger(int number)
        {
            string hash;
            using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
            {
                hash = String.Concat(md5.ComputeHash(BitConverter
                  .GetBytes(number))
                  .Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
            }
            return hash;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Hash Value for sha256 Hash(64 Characters)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The Input Data</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHash256(string data)
        {
            string hashResult = string.Empty;

            if (data != null)
            {
                using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create())
                {
                    byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                    byte[] dataBufferHashed = sha256.ComputeHash(dataBuffer);
                    hashResult = GetHashString(dataBufferHashed);
                }
            }
            return hashResult;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Hash Value for MD5 Hash(32 Characters)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The Input Data</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHashMD5(string data)
        {
            string hashResult = string.Empty;
            if (data != null)
            {
                using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                    byte[] dataBufferHashed = md5.ComputeHash(dataBuffer);
                    hashResult = GetHashString(dataBufferHashed);
                }
            }
            return hashResult;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Encrypted Hash Data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataBufferHashed">Buffered Hash Data</param>
        /// <returns> Encrypted hash String </returns>
        private static string GetHashString(byte[] dataBufferHashed)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in dataBufferHashed)
            {
                sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Modify / any better solution for this code is always welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
  int source = 123;
  String hash;

  // Do not omit "using" - should be disposed
  using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()) 
  {
    hash = String.Concat(md5.ComputeHash(BitConverter
      .GetBytes(source))
      .Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
  }

  // Test
  // d119fabe038bc5d0496051658fd205e6
  Console.Write(hash);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what is the md5 hash of "meaning of life" you can

```
int meaningOfLife = 42;
var result = CalculateMD5Hash(""+meaningOfLife);
```

This assumes you can

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Other then that I do not see why you would do this, integers are stored in 4 bytes and you want md5 representation that is 16 bytes. You literally want number representation that takes x4 times the space, it does not add anything, as this is easily reversible.

Comment: this is also lazy, by assuming .NET would just do the conversion to string from an integer for you by appending it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your integer into a byte array then you can do this:

```
byte[] hashValue;
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    hashValue = md5.ComputeHash(BitConverter.GetBytes(5));
}
```

Comment: Since `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5` implements `IDisposable` you have to *dispose* the created instance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
int intValue = ; // your value
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
Array.Reverse(intBytes);
byte[] result = intBytes; // you are most probably working on a little-endian machine
byte[] hash = ((HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(result);

// string representation (similar to UNIX format)
string encoded = BitConverter.ToString(hash)
   // without dashes
   .Replace("-", string.Empty)
   // make lowercase
   .ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

using some performance-focused features (e.g. span and stackalloc) to allocate less memory during hashing!

usage:

```cs
var number = 42;
var hash = number.ToString().ToMD5();
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class MD5Extensions
{
    public static string ToMd5(this string input)
    {
        var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

        return inputBytes.ToMd5(0, inputBytes.Length);
    }

    public static string ToMd5(this byte[] inputBytes, int offset, int count)
    {
        Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[32];

        inputBytes.ToMd5(offset, count, chars);

        return chars.ToString();
    }

     public static void ToMd5(this byte[] input, int offset, int count, Span<char> destination)
    {
        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(input, offset, count);

        var charsWritten = 0;
        const string format = "X2";

        foreach (var hashByte in hashBytes)
        {
            if (hashByte.TryFormat(destination, out charsWritten, format))
            {
                destination = destination.Slice(charsWritten);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"byte '{hashByte}' could not be parsed using format '{format}' and avaible space of {destination.Length}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```